# ASP NET Entity Framework Insert - Unable to update the EntitySet

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer un **Insert** con Entity Framework, pero tengo cuando quiero hacer el **Add** obtengo esto error.

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'HomeCounters' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

Justo aquí.

> db.SaveChanges();

Este error me manda cuanda hago el id auto incrementable

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'Unable to update the EntitySet 'HomeCounters' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.'

Este es mi código, alguien sabe a que se deba?

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertCounters(string id_userCreated, string texto, string value)
    {

        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {

            var counter = new HomeCounters()
            {
                text = texto,
                value = value,
                id = RandomNumber(1, 1000000000)

            };
            db.HomeCounters.Add(counter);
            //db..add(cat);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var action = "Insert";
        var comments = "Contadores ingresada por el usuario : ";
        InsertInBitacora(id_userCreated, action, comments + id_userCreated);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Esta es la clase que estoy usando

```
    public partial class HomeCounters
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos la definición de la clase `HomeCounters`?

Comment: como mapeas la entidad HomeCounters en DBEnt ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini con un Entity Data Model que lee mi bd y me genera todo

Comment: ok pero entonces este HomeCounters es una tabla? no sera una view ? porque las view no son actualizables son de solo lectura

Comment: porque usas un random para el id de la entidad, esa es una pesima idea, deberia ser un secuencial que ingremente desde el ultimo id existente, o en caso contrario un GUID

Comment: @LeandroTuttini , pues originalmente tenía id como identity, pero me da un error similar, entonces decidí pasarle un valor de id

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Comment: La clase `RandomNumber` cómo la importas o a que ensamblado pertenece?, por que no logro que la reconozca ASP.NET MVC en mi aplicación de pruebas.

Comment: Si `RandomNumber` es una clase que tu mismo implementas, podrías poner el código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#key

### Clave

Entity Framework se basa en todas las entidades que contienen un valor de clave que se usa para la entidad de seguimiento. Una convención de Code First es propiedades de clave implícitas; Código primero busca una propiedad denominada "Id" o una combinación de nombre de clase y "Id", por ejemplo, "BlogId". Esta propiedad se asignará a una columna de clave principal en la base de datos.

Las clases Blog y Post siguen esta convención. ¿Qué ocurre si no? ¿Qué ocurre si Blog usa el nombre PrimaryTrackingKey en su lugar, o incluso foo? Si el código en primer lugar no encuentra una propiedad que coincide con esta convención producirá una excepción debido a requisitos de Entity Framework que debe tener una propiedad de clave. Puede usar la anotación de clave para especificar qué propiedad es que se usará como valor EntityKey.

Ahora bien, en tu código:

Modelo:

```
public partial class HomeCounters
{
    [key] //Esto es lo que necesitas.
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador:

```
var counter = new HomeCounters() {
    text = texto,
    value = value 
    // id = RandomNumber(1, 1000000000) //Esto es innecesario.
};
```